# Read controls used on page or usercontrol from another project

Tags: c#, reflection, user-controls

I have 2 projects in a solution. A web project and a forms project and i want the forms project to list the webcontrols that are used inside a user control (.ascx) in the web project.

I can read the .ascx as a textfile and parse it, but i was wondering if there is a better way to do this. I can reference the web project within the forms project, but i don't know how to read/loop through the controls of a page or user control as they are protected.

Can this perhaps be done with reflection? Or is there another approach i should take?